# Switch between multiple (5-7) images on click and loop

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to have a really simple gallery of around 5-7 images, where you can click on the image and it switches to the next one, and by the end it circles back to the beginning. My code right now only allows me to have 3 images, where it just loops between image 2 and image 3.

```
function swaparrows(obj, i1, i2, i3) {
  var src = obj.getAttribute('src');

  if (src.match(i1))
    obj.setAttribute('src', i2);

  else
    obj.setAttribute('src', i1);
}
```

And for the HTML:

```
<img src="https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/og/player/Druio.png" 
  onclick="swaparrows(this, 'https://camblab.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pool-water.jpg', 'https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article13348246.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/0_SupernumeraryRainbows_Entwistle_13621-610x859.jp', 'https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/og/player/Druio.png')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an attribute on the element to figure out what the current index is. Then, increment that index by one and cap it off at the end of the array via the modulus operator so that it cycles circularly. Also, please do not use `onclick` for such long code snippets because it makes code very unmaintainable. Also, if you are not using jQuery, then apply to the whole page so that you can easily and quickly add new interactive content. If you are using jQuery, then do not do this because your page will get very laggy very quickly because jQuery embodies and promotes poor performance.

<sup>Because it appears as though you are new to Stackoverflow, I shall explain this checkmark here. After reading and reviewing my answer, if (and only if) you are thoroughly satisfied with the answer I have posted here, then you can reward me by clicking this checkmark to accept this answer as the best answer. If someone else posts a better answer, then click their checkmark. Clicking a checkmark is not permanent: if someone later on post a better answer, then you can click their checkmark and switch the best answer over to the new answer posted.</sup>

```html
<img src="https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/og/player/Druio.png" 
     data-swap-index="2"
     data-swap-0="https://camblab.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pool-water.jpg"
     data-swap-1="https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article13348246.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/0_SupernumeraryRainbows_Entwistle_13621-610x859.jpg"
     data-swap-2="https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/og/player/Druio.png" 
     style="max-height:80vh" decoding="async" />

<img src="https://www.minecraft.net/content/dam/archive/og-image/minecraft-hero-og.jpg" 
     data-swap-index="0"
     data-swap-0="https://www.minecraft.net/content/dam/archive/og-image/minecraft-hero-og.jpg"
     data-swap-1="https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple123/v4/10/29/2f/10292fd0-d87a-6856-7523-f67fa8051df7/AppIcon-0-1x_U007emarketing-0-85-220-9.png/246x0w.jpg" 
     style="max-height:80vh" decoding="async" />

<script>
addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    // when anywhere on the page is clicked, this will fire
    var eventObj = evt || window.event;
    var target = eventObj.target;
    var swapIndex = target.getAttribute("data-swap-index");
    if (swapIndex !== null) {
        var newSwapIndex = (swapIndex|0) + 1|0;
        if (!target.hasAttribute("data-swap-" + newSwapIndex)) {
            // cycle back to the first image
            newSwapIndex = 0;
        }
        
        // now apply the new swap index
        target.setAttribute(
            "src",
            target.getAttribute("data-swap-" + newSwapIndex)
        );
        target.setAttribute("data-swap-index", newSwapIndex);
        
        eventObj.preventDefault(); // prevent link from opening or something
    } // else the element being clicked on is not swappable
});
</script>
```

Notice how I prefix the attributes with `data`. All attributes prefixed with `data-` have been set aside for special custom use purposes by the WhatWG [with datasets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), thus it is always a good idea to prefix custom attributes with `data-` in order to ensure that in the future the attribute the you use is not added to the specification with special effects based upon its value.